# Right way or event to choose what view load in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working in an app that logs in an user if there isn't another user already logged in at launch time. This way the first view to appear should be the Login View. But in the case there is a logged user already, the first view appearing should be the main menu. Im handling this with the viewWillAppear function and it's working, but I don't know if this is the correct approach or how it should be handle in this situations.

Here is my code. My first view is MainMenuVC in which I control if there is a logged user or not, then I choose if stay in main menu view or push my login view.

```
class MainMenuVC: UIViewController {


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if (UserMgr.users.count == 0){
        var vc1:LoginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") as LoginVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc1, animated: false)
    }
    else
    {
        //I do nothing so this view is loaded
    }


}
```

I don't know if i should use another ViewController and implement the function loadView() to decide what view load, but the problem is make that view work with the story board and my navigation controller. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try rephrasing your first sentences, because it is rather hard to extract what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks, I was heavily confused by "lunch" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will have two different view controllers, one for the login screen (`VCLogin`) and one for the main menu (`VCMainMenu`). Now, in your `AppDelegate` there are methods which are called, when the app launches respectively when it appears. So, place the code checking whether a user is logged in there and make the appropriate view controller the root view controller, e.g.

```
let navigationController = window.rootViewController as UINavigationController

navigationController.rootViewController =
    userIsLoggedIn ? mainMenuViewController : loginViewController
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I totally forgot about the app delegate  methods, but if I have two choose between which view or view controller load  evaluating some condition after the app launch. How should i do it?

Comment: You'd instantiate them there, because they do not exist yet. Basically, the `mainMenuViewController` and `loginViewController` variables are instances, I just not showed where they are created, assuming they are already there. For creation the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` which you already mentioned is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I have one last doubt before configure app delegate my initial view controller in the storyboard was mainMenuVC, so after login should I instantiate the app delegate and change the de root view controller again?

Comment: No, in that case you'd exchange the VC. I think the best way to do it, is to add `mainMenuVC` on top and remove `loginVC`. But maybe you'd want to google on this topic.

Comment: Please search for the error message. And if you cannot find any solution, you are welcome to open a new question.